# Override or add methods to already loaded Classes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activesupport

I'm trying to add functionalities to ActiveSupport::TimeWithZone class addind the following file to my rails project:

**lib/active_support/time_with_zone.rb**

```
class ActiveSupport::TimeWithZone
  def in_time_zone_(new_zone = ::Time.zone)
    Time.zone.parse(in_time_zone(new_zone).strftime('%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S'))
  end
end
```

and in

**config/application.rb**

```
config.autoload_paths << "#{Rails.root}/lib"
```

I can use other custom modules in my lib directory but this one seems to be ignored. Any idea why?

[image]

Comment: Why do you believe it's being ignored?

Comment: I updated the question with the behavior

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rails loads code for you when you try to use an undefined constant: the `const_missing` hook rails sets up is called, searches `autoload_paths` for a file with a name that corresponds to the constant and then requires it.

In your case this code will never be invoked: the `TimeWithZone` class is loaded during the loading of rails' itself.

You can either put your monkey patch in something that does always get loaded (for example in an initialiser) or require it explicitly from an initialiser.

Answer (score 1):

All monkey patches usually stored in `config/initializers` dir.
I placed your code in `config/initializers/active_support_time_with_zone.rb`

Here is my example

```
2.1.2 :005 > r = Reason.last
  Reason Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "reasons".* FROM "reasons" ORDER BY "reasons"."id" DESC LIMIT 1
 => #<Reason id: 3, name: "R3", project_id: 3, created_at: "2016-05-04 06:43:25", updated_at: "2016-05-04 06:43:25", deleted: false>
2.1.2 :006 > r.created_at.class
 => ActiveSupport::TimeWithZone
2.1.2 :007 > r.created_at.in_time_zone_
 => Wed, 04 May 2016 06:43:25 UTC +00:00
2.1.2 :010 > Time.zone = "Novosibirsk"
 => "Novosibirsk"
2.1.2 :011 > Time.zone
 => #<ActiveSupport::TimeZone:0x007fbcd695ad90 @name="Novosibirsk", @utc_offset=nil, @tzinfo=#<TZInfo::TimezoneProxy: Asia/Novosibirsk>, @current_period=nil>
2.1.2 :012 > r.created_at.in_time_zone_
 => Wed, 04 May 2016 13:43:25 NOVT +07:00
2.1.2 :013 >
```

I used code you provided

```
class ActiveSupport::TimeWithZone
  def in_time_zone_(new_zone = ::Time.zone)
    Time.zone.parse(in_time_zone(new_zone).strftime('%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S'))
  end
end
```

My app uses `gem 'rails', '4.0.3'`

Hope that helps.

Comment: thank you, you were right but Frederick explain better the whole ratio

Answer (score 1):

Actually Rails is far smart than you think, path you put in `autoload_paths` array is for future use. In `development` environment `eager loading` of classes if put `off`. So classes are only loaded into memory or `required` only when you code needs.

When needed, Rails searches the `file` by the `class` and `namespace`.

**Example**:
If it sees `ActiveSupport::TimeWithZone` it expects the path to be
`lib/active_support/time_with_zone.rb`.

`lib` is there because you put the `lib` directory in the array.

But this is not the case for `initializers` directory. As all the files in this directory are considered important and loaded when Rails boots up.

See this for more info
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/autoloading_and_reloading_constants.html#autoload-paths

Comment: thank you, you were right but Frederick explain better the whole ratio